# How to say "I suggest adding [something]"

Tags: verbs, licensing

I said to my employee:

> I suggest adding dtUpdate column to the table.

For me it sounds wrong. I want to say:

> I suggest to add dtUpdate column to the table.

But I know by verb pattern this is wrong.

Comment: You appear to recognize that *suggest* ordinarily takes the *-ing* form in its complement. What then is your question?

Comment: I suggest [that] **you** add **a** dtUpdate column to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Suggest doing something* is perfectly fine, and idiomatic.

> I **suggested going** in my car.

> Thus, to restore the fun and integrity to the sport, I **suggest implementing** the following rules.

> If you want it avoid the 405 this weekend, I **suggest cutting** through Cold Water Canyon.

As for using *suggest* + infinitive, the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* doesn't have any sentence using *suggest* that way.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two choices here.

> I suggest adding ...

is a kind of passive which makes the suggestion polite. You can also use the [present tense subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive):

> I suggest *that you add* ...

This is a stronger suggestion because it also suggests who should do the work ("you"), not only that it be done by someone. This can be softened by changing from *I* to *we*:

> I suggest *that we add* ...

which is then a suitable alternative for the first form, of about equal "strength", or perhaps even softer: the addition is to be done by us as a team, not necessarily you. We should have this addition, but if you don't feel like doing it, it can be another one of us.

---

By the way: we need an article in your sentences:

> I suggest adding {a | the} `foo_count` column to the table.

Use "a" if it is a new column that you just invented.

> I suggest adding *a* {`foo_count` column | column named `foo_count`} to the table whose purpose will be to maintain the count of foo events received by the widget represented by each table row.

Use "the" if it is an existing column in some table:

> I suggest adding *the* `foo_count` column that we have in the `bar_table` to this table also.